# Upgrading scripts to Python 3 - \r\n & text binary mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, newline

Really struggling with something that should be pretty basic. I'm looking to identify instances where \n does not have a reciprocal \r (i.e. \r\n is good x\n is bad and would ).

I appreciate this is because python 2 managed 'rb' differently but can't work out the equivalent function or way of identifying \r in python 3.

```
import re
import sys
import time
with open('4 - raw.txt', 'rb') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()

newLinePos = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('\n', content)]

for line in newLinePos:
    if (content[line-1]) != '\r':
        print (repr(content[line-20:line]))

print ("end")
time.sleep(1000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3 makes a clear distinction between raw byte strings, and utf-8 string. `content[line-1]` is returning a number, probably 0-255 - the byte, and you are trying to match it to a string, `'\r'`. I agree possibly the conversion could be made, but Python is strongly typed, so this will always fail, regardless of what character the integer represents. To get the `byte` number corresponding to `\r` use:

```
(content[line-1]) != ord('\r')
```

and similarly use a bytes string for your iterator generation:

```
newLinePos = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(b'\n', content)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the location of line feed / newline (`\n`) characters not preceded by a carriage return (`\r`) you can use a *negative* *lookbehind* *assertion* regular expression.

```
>>> lines = ['foo', 'ba\nr', 'baz', 'quux']
>>> content = '\r\n'.join(lines).encode('utf-8')
>>> content
b'foo\r\nba\nr\r\nbaz\r\nquux'
>>> pattern = b'(?<!\r)\n'
>>> newLinePos = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(pattern, content)]
>>> newLinePos
[7]
>>> content[5:8]
b'ba\n'
```

There are a couple of things to note.

1. `content` is a `bytes` instance; when you read from a file in 'rb' mode you'll get bytes.
2. `pattern` needs to be a bytes instance, because the sequence being searched is a bytes instance.
3. The pattern `(?<!\r)\n` matches if the character following the parentheses (`\n`) is not preceded by the `\r`.  See the [re documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) for a full description.